# how to make grouping in list using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make sorted group in jquery here is my code
https://jsbin.com/xabohupuzu/edit?html,js,output

```
$(function(){

  var data =['c','d','c','abc','dee','pu','gu']
          function showItemsInList(data, element){
            var str=''
           for(var i=0;i<data.sort().length;i++){
             str+='<li>'+data[i]+'</li>';
           }
            element.append(str);

        }
  showItemsInList(data,$('.abc ul'))

})
```

**output**

```
<ul>
<li>abc</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>c</li>
<li>d</li>
<li>dee</li>
<li>gu</li>
<li>pu</li>
</ul>
```

**Expected output**

```
 <ul>
      <li> A---D</li>
       <li>abc</li>
        <li>c</li>
        <li>c</li>
         <li>d</li>
         <li>dee</li>
        <li> E---I</li>
          <li>gu</li>
       <li> J---P</li>
          <li>pu</li>
       <li> Q---Z</li>
       </ul>
```

I am able to sort my data.But I want to know I will make group in jquery

Comment: Should do sort before the loop, not every iteration. Do you want predefined groups?

Comment: yes they are predefined group

Comment: they are predefined group a--d , e--i, j---p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group the data in advance by using an array for the last letter of the group and an array with all groups for the result.

```js
var data = ['c', 'd', 'c', 'abc', 'dee', 'pu', 'gu'],
    groups = ['A--D', 'E--I', 'J--P', 'Q--Z'],
    groupIndex = 0,
    result = '';

result += '<ul>';
result += '<li>' + groups[groupIndex] + '</li>';
data
    .sort()
    .forEach(function (s) {
        if (s[0].toLowerCase() > groups[groupIndex].slice(-1).toLowerCase()) {
            result += '<li>' + groups[++groupIndex] + '</li>';
        }
        result += '<li>' + s + '</li>';
    });
while (++groupIndex < groups.length) {
    result += '<li>' + groups[groupIndex] + '</li>';
}
result += '</ul>';
document.body.innerHTML += result;
```

Comment: this is not my expected answer

Comment: see my expected answer

Comment: don't use es6 syntex pls use es5